# How to solve this 'SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^function authenticate(req, res, next)'?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on backend (Express, Node, Mongo). I set up https with OpenSSL and as required I made changes into bin/www and in app.js. I'm geting very unfamiliar error and very long error. I'm including it here.

```
E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\path-to-regexp\index.js:128

return new RegExp(path, flags);
         ^
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    if (http\.IncomingMessage\.prototype\.logIn
        && http\.IncomingMessage\.prototype\.logIn !== IncomingMessageExt\.logIn) {
      require('\.\.\/framework\/connect')\.__monkeypatchNode();
    }

\/\/ accumulator for failures from each strategy in the chain
var failures = [];

function allFailed() {
  if (callback) {
    if (!multi) {
      return callback(null, false, failures[0]\.challenge, failures[0]\.status);
    } else {
      var challenges = failures\.map(function(f) { return f\.challenge; });
      var statuses = failures\.map(function(f) { return f\.status; });
      return callback(null, false, challenges, statuses);
    }
  }
..................................................................
..................................................................
..................................................................
at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at pathtoRegexp (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\path-to-regexp\index.js:128:10)
    at new Layer (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:45:17)
    at Function.route (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:494:15)
    at Function.proto.<computed> [as get] (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:509:22)
    **at Object.<anonymous> (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\routes\users.js:12:8)**
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    **at Object.<anonymous> (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\app.js:13:19)** 
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! confusionserver@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the confusionserver@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-07T04_31_33_225Z-debug.log
```

users.js line 12:

```
 router.get( authenticate.verifyUser, authenticate.verifyAdmin, '/', function(req, res, next) {
  User.find({})
  .then((users) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.json(users);
}, (err) => next(err))
.catch((err) => next(err));
});
```

app.js line 13:

```
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
```

So, where am I missing? Why I'm getting that error? Before changing the code for OpenSSL everything was working fine and now this.
My Node version is: v12.18.1, express: 4.16.1, npm: 6.14.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path argument for `router.get()` has to come first.

Change this:

```
router.get( authenticate.verifyUser, authenticate.verifyAdmin, '/', ...)
```

to this:

```
router.get('/', authenticate.verifyUser, authenticate.verifyAdmin, ...)
```

The error is attempting to show that you're passing `authenticate.verifyUser` where Express expects either a string or a regex, but you're passing a function.

FYI, this is an interesting example for where TypeScript could be helpful.  This could have been a compile error about a wrong argument type for the first argument, instead of a cryptic run-time error.

---

From the [Express doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get.method), the signature for `app.get()` is this:

```
app.get(path, callback [, callback ...])
```

The path must be first followed by one or more callbacks.